# How to unload an UIview from UINavigationController?

Tags: iphone, sdk, uinavigationcontroller

I'm using a UINavigationController for traveling between different views.

The last of the views need to be dynamic as selected in the previous view. The `viewDidLoad` method does not help, as the content is the same as the first time. I need to know how to unload uiview ...

I have also tried `viewDidAppear`; in this case the objects previously created are not deleted and the new objects are loaded over the others.

What should I do, unload when I change to another view or I go back?

Comment: UINavigationController is used to travell between controllers, not views. And besides that I have no idea of what you are trying to accomplish. What do you mean by unload the view? where are the viewDidUnload methods you are talking about? Can you place some code to make it clear?

Comment: Well... then I seek to eliminate everything that I've created dynamically from this controller, so when I go back and I enter again into the controller I want to rebuild the dinamic content. I think that viewDidDisappear will work. thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to unload your viewcontroller in `viewDidDisapper` method.

I think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a `subview`, you should just be able to call the `removeFromSuperView`